# comparison of several attributes in one SQL query

Tags: sql, teradata

I want tow write a Teradata SQL query.

I have two attributes: date and name.

I want to create do a comparison for those two only using ONE subquery. I want it to look something like:

```
date,name= SELECT date, name FROM ...
```

Is it possible? How does that syntax look like

Comment: I don't have intimate knowledge of Teradata but have you tried parenthesis?: (date,name) = select date, name from ...

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  You are selecting date and name from some table, what exactly are you trying to compare them to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
SELECT {columns}
  FROM {TableA}
 WHERE (date,name) IN (SELECT date, name FROM {TableB});
```